# Cordova Android LocalStorage loses last saved item when removing battery/running out of battery

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, local-storage

**Versions:**
Cordova: 10.0.0
Cordova-Android: 9.0.0

**Goal:**
Items saved to the LocalStorage should be persisted immediately and across whatever happens.

**Investigation:**
I first came across this issue when I left the app running over the weekend. When I came back the phone's battery was empty and after starting the app some data of the LocalStorage was lost.

So I did some tests and first I couldn't really reproduce the issue. What I tried:
Writing data into LocalStorage (`localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar')`)

- Force quit the app
- Restart the device while the app is running
- Playing around with airplane mode (doesn't make too much sense)

Then I actually managed reproducing the issue:

- Writing data into LocalStorage (`localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar')`)
- Remove device battery while app is still running
- Start device/app and it's gone. `localStorage.getItem('foo') => undefined`

I ran the next test:

- Writing data into LocalStorage:
  `localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar')`
  `localStorage.setItem('foo2', 'bar2')`
- Remove device battery while app is still running
- Start device/app and it's partially gone:
  `localStorage.getItem('foo') => 'bar'`
  `localStorage.getItem('foo2') => undefined`

So it seems as the last stored item gets lost. Which doesn't make too much sense to me.
I tried to figure out where the Android Webview persists the LocalStorage to, to verify if the data is persisted to the file system after a `setItem` call.

The best thing I could find was this command to access the LocalStorage Log file.
`adb exec-out run-as com.package.name cat /data/data/com.package.name/app_webview/Default/Local\ Storage/leveldb/000003.log`

So every time I did an action like `setItem`, or after removing the battery I checked the LocalStorage log file directly on the device.

- After `localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar')` => `file://...foo...bar` was added to the log file.
- After removing the battery and restart the device => `file://...foo...bar` was not present any more in the log file.

**Summary:**
LocalStorage loses the last set item when removing the battery while the app is still running.

My current fix would be to always call an additional `setItem` with the current timestamp, but I really would like to find a proper solution for that.

**Questions:**
How can I check the current persisted LocalStorage Object in the Android file system?
Why is this even happening and how do I best fix it?

Comment: You are basically saying the data is not saved when you pull the battery while it's trying to save. Not sure what else you are expecting as behavior.

Comment: I would totally understand that behaviour if I pull the battery immediately after saving. But I always waited several seconds and did also some tests where I waited minutes before pulling the battery. I also checked the LocalStorage in the browser debugger and in the android file system log to be present before pulling the battery.